# DynamoDB EMR Hive Connector writes 1 item at a time

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

While writing to dynamodb with on-demand capacity using hive `> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t SELECT * FROM s3data;` I notice that it writes 1 item at a time which is evident from the writecapacity graph below. Here are the settings

```
SET dynamodb.throughput.write.percent=1.0;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (userId string, categoryName string, score double)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "data.reader-score.test",
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "userId:userId,categoryName:categoryName,score:score", 
"dynamodb.throughput.write" = "5000");
```

Is there any other configuration that must be done?

[image]

Comment: Can you retry without setting the write percentage?

Comment: The problem is because of the "EMR Hive DynamoDb" connector, which is fixed from 5.22+ of EMR, will provide more details in the answer late